# Error while installing python setuptools

Tags: linux, centos, python

I downloaded `ez_Setup.py` from [here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py).

I have python 2.6 on CentOS 6.

When I do this:

```
python ez_setup.py
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Downloading http://cheeseshop.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6a8-py2.6.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 214, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "ez_setup.py", line 147, in main
    egg = download_setuptools(version, to_dir=tmpdir, delay=0)
  File "ez_setup.py", line 128, in download_setuptools
    src = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 429, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 616, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same error when trying to access to http://cheeseshop.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6a8-py2.6.egg, the file doesn't exists. But, there are

> [setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg) 
>   [setuptools-0.6c10-py2.6.egg](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c10-py2.6.egg) 
>   [setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg)

that are available, so if you manually download and install the last one ([setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg)) it will work.

The other problem I noticed, is that the `ez_setup.py` script I downloaded from the url you gave (and it is perfectly working by downloading the correct `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg`) doesn't correspond with the error lines you gave in your question, maybe the script you have is an old version, just re-download it and try to relaunch it.